# Can i use my Domain controller and sql virtual machines with 2 sharepoint servers

Tags: 2013

I have these severs,

Domain Controller 1

SQL Server 1

SharePoint Foundation 1

Can I add SharePoint Server 2013 server to this topology so that it will use same domain controller and same sql server

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, you can install the SharePoint 2013 on the same SQL server along with other SharePoint servers. But keep in mind this type of configuration is only recommend for the Dev/Testing farm not for production.

Reason is, One SQL server hosting two SharePoint farm will increase the pressure on it.